# Assigning value to all rows of grouped variable given multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have a data frame with a grouped ID variable. For each record within each grouped ID, we need to assign a value to a new column that is our 'final value' based on conditions from another column. I do this type of thing typically in a manner of loops, which while inefficient is usually not too impactful for me, but here the data is large and it would take too long. How can I convert the logic below to apply family of functions for efficiency? I have a very hard time understanding these functions.

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame("Group_ID" = c(1,1,2,2), "Values" = c("A", "B", "B", "C"))

df_list <- list()
for(grp_id in levels(unique(as.factor(df$Group_ID)))){
  grp <- df[df$Group_ID == grp_id, ]
  vals <- droplevels(unique(as.factor(grp$Values)))
  
  if("C" %in% vals){
    final_value <- "C"
  } else if("B" %in% vals){
    final_value <- "B"
  } else{
    final_value <- "A"
  }
  
  grp$Final_Value <- final_value
  df_list[[grp_id]] <- grp
}
new_df <- rbindlist(df_list)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R approach that may work for you. I will add further explanation, and hope that this is helpful.

First, take your `Values` column and convert to an ordered factor:

```
df$Values <- ordered(df$Values, levels = c("C", "B", "A"))
```

Ordered factors are useful for ordinal or ordered data. The levels here have directional signs (in this case, `<`) indicating that it is ordered.

```
R> df$Values

[1] A B B C
Levels: C < B < A
```

This is helpful for specifying priority values of "C", "B", and "A".

Then we use `ave`, and specify the function `FUN` to use as `min` for minumum:

```
df$Final_Value <- ave(df$Values, df$Group_ID, FUN = min)
```

Here is more details on how this works with `ave`. First, the `ave` function is this:

```
function (x, ..., FUN = mean) 
{
  if (missing(...)) 
    x[] <- FUN(x)
  else {
    g <- interaction(...)
    split(x, g) <- lapply(split(x, g), FUN)
  }
  x
}
```

This function will first `split` a given vector by group (so we can apply some function to each group). In our case we want to work by each `Group_ID` independently. If we `split` the whole data frame, we would have:

```
R> split(df, df$Group_ID)

$`1`
  Group_ID Values
1        1      A
2        1      B

$`2`
  Group_ID Values
3        2      B
4        2      C
```

In our case, if we `split` just `df$Values` we get:

```
R> split(df$Values, df$Group_ID)

$`1`
[1] A B
Levels: C < B < A

$`2`
[1] B C
Levels: C < B < A
```

Note that even after splitting by group, each group will show all levels for the factor (A, B, and C) even if only some of the values (e.g., only A and B) are present.

Then, `ave` uses `lapply` to apply the `min` function to each of these two groups. `lapply` will iterate through each group, and determine the minimum value within that group using `min`.

With our factor, each level has an associated integer value in the background. As it is ordered, it is clear which levels are less than or greater than others (`Levels: C < B < A`). In this case, if any value is C the result will be C, as this is the lowest value based on our ordered levels. If the lowest value is B, then B will be the result. Note that whatever the lowest value is for a given group will be included for all rows within that group (e.g., if one value is C, then all rows in that group will be C).

In the end, you just need:

```
df$Values <- ordered(df$Values, levels = c("C", "B", "A"))
df$Final_Value <- ave(df$Values, df$Group_ID, FUN = min)
```

I hope this is helpful.

**Output**

```
  Group_ID Values Final_Value
1        1      A           B
2        1      B           B
3        2      B           C
4        2      C           C
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Group_ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2), Values = c("A", "B", 
"B", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: works. not finding the description very intuitive however "Subsets of x[] are averaged, where each subset consist of those observations with the same factor levels." in this case ```x = ``` numeric factor levels of ```Values```.  Its subsetting on ```Group_ID```.  We are taking a minumum, which means that all factor levels of ```Values``` will not be present in each subset, or else it would only return the level of 1 for all subsets. What am I missing?

Comment: Good question. All levels will be present after grouping with `split`. See edited answer. I put in the source code for `ave` which I think may be useful. Please let me know if this is helpful.